# Get attendees for a TryBooking event as an organizer through API

Tags: rest, webhooks

I am developing an application which needs to periodically sync data from TryBooking's API. I have a developer key pair and I can act as the event organizer through the API. I need to get the basic data of the attendees for a given event (name, e-mail address), but I am having trouble getting this from the API.

Querying the event works fine, but in the response there is no trace of this data. I could not find a separate endpoint to directly query the attendees either.

What I found was that apparently the API calls a booking of an attendee for an event a 'transaction', and there are endpoints to query transactions either by an ID or by a date. Reference: https://developer.trybooking.com/#get-by-transactionid

Apparently I can get transaction ids if I set up webhooks and that way when a booking happens, my API will be called with the appropriate transaction id which I can store and then use to query the attendee data. This is fine as I wanted to set up webhooks anyway to reduce the sync delay, but I need to have an alternative. What happens if I don't get the `transactionid` due to intermittent network or devops issues, or during an app deployment? It seems to me that I have no other way to get it later.

As for the other endpoint, I cannot figure out what the date parameter does. I tried calling it with various values (the date of the event and the date of the booking included), but I always get an empty response.

I'm hoping that someone who already used the API can point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

You are correct, the expected use case is to setup webhooks (called '[Notify URL](https://learn.trybooking.com/hc/en-us/articles/360002854594-Notify-URL)' in the TryBooking) so you recieve an request every time a booking occurs.

Note that you will receive a notify call anytime the booking is edited or refunded as well as the initial booking.

Then use the get by transaction id endpoint as to [get by transaction](https://developer.trybooking.com/#get-by-transactionid) details.

As a 'reconciliation' to confirm you have received every transaction you can use the [get by date](https://developer.trybooking.com/#get-by--date) endpoint which will return all transactions on a given date. The date format is yyyy-MM-dd

For example: `/au/reporting/v1/bookings?date=2023-11-14`

If you have further issues, TryBooking has a customer support team referenced on their website I've found quite helpful with details or help to any specific issues encountered.